# Filter complex datetime sequence using R

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

**Background**

I have a dataset: df, where I would like to, first, establish a startime with the **first** instance of a 'Connect' value, and then create an endtime, *only* if the difference between rows is *not* 60 seconds or less. I would also like to drop duplicate values. Finally, I would like to *remove all the Attempt values*. The final output should only have 'Connect' and 'Ended call' columns.

```
Action          Time

Attempt        3/12/2020 10:02:43 AM
Attempt        3/12/2020 10:02:48 AM
Connect        3/12/2020 10:02:49 AM
Ended call     3/12/2020 10:11:02 AM
Attempt        3/12/2020 10:11:24 AM
Connect        3/12/2020 10:11:24 AM
Ended call     3/12/2020 10:12:22 AM
Attempt        3/12/2020 10:12:34 AM
Connect        3/12/2020 10:12:34 AM
Ended call     3/12/2020 11:20:33 AM
Ended call     3/12/2020 11:20:37 AM
Attempt        3/12/2020 11:21:08 AM
Connect        3/12/2020 11:21:09 AM
Ended call     3/12/2020 12:01:13 PM
Ended call     3/12/2020 12:04:02 PM
Attempt        3/12/2020 1:06:10 PM
Connect        3/12/2020 1:06:12 PM
Ended call     3/12/2020 2:00:10 PM
Ended call     3/12/2020 2:04:51 PM
Attempt        3/12/2020 2:04:57 PM
Connect        3/12/2020 2:04:58 PM
Ended call     3/12/2020 2:50:24 PM
Ended call     3/12/2020 2:50:46 PM
```

Desired Output

```
Connect                 Ended Call

3/12/2020 10:02:49 AM   3/12/2020 10:11:02 AM
3/12/2020 10:11:24 AM   3/12/2020 11:20:33 AM
3/12/2020 11:21:09 AM   3/12/2020 12:01:13 PM
3/12/2020 1:06:12 PM    3/12/2020 2:00:10 PM
3/12/2020 2:04:58 PM    3/12/2020 2:50:24 PM
```

Dput

```
df <- structure(list(Action = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Attempt", "Connect", 
"Ended call"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 
3L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("", "3/12/2020 1:06:10 PM", "3/12/2020 1:06:12 PM", 
"3/12/2020 10:02:43 AM", "3/12/2020 10:02:48 AM", "3/12/2020 10:02:49 AM", 
"3/12/2020 10:11:02 AM", "3/12/2020 10:11:24 AM", "3/12/2020 10:12:22 AM", 
 "3/12/2020 10:12:34 AM", "3/12/2020 11:20:33 AM", "3/12/2020 11:20:37 AM", 
"3/12/2020 11:21:08 AM", "3/12/2020 11:21:09 AM", "3/12/2020 12:01:13 PM", 
"3/12/2020 12:04:02 PM", "3/12/2020 2:00:10 PM", "3/12/2020 2:04:51 PM", 
 "3/12/2020 2:04:57 PM", "3/12/2020 2:04:58 PM", "3/12/2020 2:50:24 PM", 
 "3/12/2020 2:50:46 PM"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -46L))
```

I have tried this:
A talented member from Stack helped me, and this works great, except on my larger dataset, I have cases where some datetimes aren't being recorded:

```
  df2<-df %>%
   mutate(Time1 = mdy_hms(Time)) %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(Action == 'Connect')) %>% 
   mutate(Diff = difftime(Time1, lag(Time1), unit = 'sec'),
     Diff = case_when(any(Diff <=60) ~ 60, TRUE ~ as.numeric(Diff))) %>%
  filter(Action == 'Connect'|Diff >60) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(rleid(Action))) %>% 
  select(Action, Time)


 library(data.table)
   df %>% 
 mutate(rn = rowid(Action)) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = Action, values_from = Date) %>%
 select(-rn)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In don't understand the logic in your second row. There's a connect at 10:11:24 but you've paired that with the End at 10:11:24 even though there was another connect at 10:12:34 that seems to be more likely associated with that end. Are you sure that's what you want? Why did you drop the 10:12:34  connect?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, yes, I dropped this because his datetime is within 60 seconds of the one above it. (or a duplicate timestamp)

Comment: So you want to drop any rows that are less than 60 seconds after the one before it no matter the action. What if you have three events (A,B and C) with 40 seconds between A and B and B and C. What do you keep? Do you drop both B and C? Because after you drop B then there's 80 seconds between A and C.

Comment: The 'Connect' (A) establishes the first timestamp, and then from there, I was hoping to have a code that looks to the next row (B) and compares it to (C). I would keep the End value if it is not less than 60, but drop it, if it were. The pattern should always follow  "Connect" and "Ended call"

Comment: @TanishaHudson, it seems rows with `Action = Attempt` are not of use at all right? Perhaps we can first filter these rows out, base on the fragment of data you posted, theses could get rid of like ~30% of the rows (7 out of 23). Also, how many rows do you have in total?

Comment: yes @Quar, I see. I have about 1000 rows in my full dataset